# Draw figures in tikzpicture (covering spaces and liftings)

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I need help to draw these two pictures, in two different tikzpictures.
I would really appreciate if someone could help!

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: What are these?

Comment: You haven't given us much to go on here. If you can't draw it at all in tikz, maybe draw it on your computer so that the shapes are recognizable? it's virtually impossible to help right now without a ton of guesswork.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent I think they are UFOs. But they could be milliner's sketches.

Comment: Please consider reviewing your earlier questions and accepting an answer if one of those provided solves the problem you asked about. One of those did not even post a picture but expected people to pause a video at a certain number of seconds in order to understand what you were trying to do and, like this one, included no code and no indication of any research effort on your part at all. But you still didn't bother to thank the person who went to the trouble of answering by accepting their solution.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one idea (a partial solution as a starting point) (arguably mis-)using the [`tqft` library](http://ctan.org/pkg/tqft).

No MWE = No further comments from me.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,tqft}
\tikzset{
  tqft/cobordism outer path/.style={draw=none},
  every node/.style={text=black,font=\footnotesize},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic at (0,0) [tqft/cylinder,genus=1,draw,name=mydonut];
\draw (mydonut-hole 1) ellipse (0.75 and 0.5);
\fill (mydonut-hole 1) ++(45:0.35) coordinate (start) circle (1pt);
\fill (mydonut-hole 1) ++(200:0.5) coordinate (end) circle (1pt);
\path (mydonut-hole 1) ++(-30:0.5) coordinate (mid);
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \draw[thick,pink] (start) 
    to[out=15,in=-50,looseness=3] node[pos=0.25,right] {$g$} (end);
  \draw[thick,orange] (start) 
    to[out=-95,in=60,looseness=1.5] (mid) 
    to[out=240,in=80,looseness=1.5] node[pos=0.75,above] {$f$} (end);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]